# Imperfetto vs [stare in imperfetto + gerundio] in single past events

Tags: verbs

How do I choose between "imperfetto" and "stare + gerundio" when referring to single past events? I thought I would use the former for habits and the latter for single past events. However, I found a counterexample in  [a related 
Italian Stack Exchange question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7244/il-passato-progressivo-stare-allimperfetto-il-gerundio-o-limperfetto):

- Per una di queste stradicciole, tornava dalla passeggiata verso casa, sulla sera del giorno 7 novembre dell'anno 1628..."

Why not "stava tornando" instead of "tornava" ?

Comment: Why "stava tornando" instead of "tornava"? Have you read, for instance, http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperfetto_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/ “Habits” is just one of the uses of imperfect, and not the main one.

Comment: Reading Treccani is always a challenge for an intermediate Italian learner such as myself. Anyway, I read it now. It explicitly says that the "gerundio passato" and the "imperfetto" are interchangeable when they express a past event without a clear start/end time, during which a single event happens ("imperfetto progressive"). Could the "gerundio passato" also replace the "imperfetto" in the contexts of the "imperfetto continuo" and "imperfetto narrativo" ? I am not sure in which of these two imperfect usages my example fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Treccani Encyclopedia](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperfetto_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) explains that, when you are in a situation of what is called "imperfetto progressivo", you can use either "imperfetto" or the periphrasis "stare" (in "imperfetto") + gerund with exactly the same meaning. For instance, you can say either

> Un giorno, in camera sua, mentre lui, distratto, ***fumava*** a qualche passo da me, io, frugando in mezzo a certi libri nell’armadio, mi trovai fra le mani una fotografia (Elsa Morante, *L’isola di Arturo*)

or

> Un giorno, in camera sua, mentre lui, distratto, ***stava fumando*** a qualche passo da me, io, frugando in mezzo a certi libri nell’armadio, mi trovai fra le mani una fotografia

This article of Treccani Encyclopedia explains that one has such a "imperfetto progressivo" situation

> Quando il processo espresso dall’imperfetto è in corso senza che sia possibile determinare né quando sia iniziato né quando si concluda, e un altro evento (implicito o esplicito) si sovrappone a questo processo in un singolo istante

that is, whenever the process expressed by "imperfetto" (or by "stare" + gerund) is ongoing without it being possible to determine when it started and when it ended, and another event (implicit or explicit) overlaps this process in a single instant ("mi trovai fra le mani una fotografia" in the example above).

In [this article by Elisabetta Mauroni](https://riviste.unimi.it/index.php/ACME/article/download/3878/4021) it's explained in this way:

> quando il verbo indica «un processo colto in un singolo istante del suo svolgimento»

that is, whenever the verb express a process caught in a single moment of its development, and says that such a "imperfetto progressivo" has these two characteristics:

> - l’esistenza di un istante di focalizzazione ([...])
> - lo stato di indeterminatezza riguardante il proseguimento del processo descritto oltre tale istante di focalizzazione

that is, there exists a single focalized moment, but there is also indeterminacy about the continuation of the process described beyond that moment (one doesn't know when the process started and ended). This article gives this example of equivalent sentences:

> - In quel momento, Enrico ***dormiva*** profondamente.
> - In quel momento, Enrico ***stava dormendo*** profondamente.

This is the case in the sentence of your question (to understand it you have to seen it in the whole context of Manzoni's text):

> Per una di queste stradicciole, ***tornava*** bel bello dalla passeggiata verso casa, sulla sera del giorno 7 novembre dell'anno 1628, don Abbondio, curato d'una delle terre accennate di sopra: il nome di questa, né il casato del personaggio, non si trovan nel manoscritto, né a questo luogo né altrove. Diceva tranquillamente il suo ufizio, e talvolta, tra un salmo e l'altro, chiudeva il breviario, tenendovi dentro, per segno, l'indice della mano destra, e, messa poi questa nell'altra dietro la schiena, proseguiva il suo cammino, guardando a terra, e buttando con un piede verso il muro i ciottoli che facevano inciampo nel sentiero: poi alzava il viso, e, girati oziosamente gli occhi all'intorno, li fissava alla parte d'un monte, dove la luce del sole già scomparso, scappando per i fessi del monte opposto, si dipingeva qua e là sui massi sporgenti, come a larghe e inuguali pezze di porpora.

The first sentence, the one of your question, caughts Don Abbondio in a single well-defined moment of the action. So, in principle, you could replace "tornava" by "stava tornando" on it (even if then language wouldn't sound very "manzoniano"):

> Per una di queste stradicciole, ***stava tornando*** bel bello dalla passeggiata verso casa, sulla sera del giorno 7 novembre dell'anno 1628, don Abbondio, curato...

Nevertheless, in other uses of "imperfetto" in which there is not such a single moment of focus on the process expressed by the verb in "imperfetto" (described in detail in the linked article by Treccani Encyclopedia), one cannot replace "imperfetto" by the periphrasis "stare" (in "imperfetto") + gerund. For instance, in this example

> In quell’estate andavo in Po, un’ora o due, al mattino. Mi piaceva sudare al remo e poi cacciarmi nell’acqua fredda, ancora buia, che entra negli occhi e li lava. Andavo quasi sempre solo, perché Pieretto a quell’ora se ne dormiva (Cesare Pavese, *Il diavolo sulle colline*)

you cannot replace "andavo", "piaceva", etc. by "stavo andando", "stava piacendo", etc.